How to overwrite a chrome shortcut?
i am trying to write a chrome extension that manages keyboard shortcuts in chrome.
The documentation for the commands api for Chrome Extensions says:

Certain Chrome shortcuts (e.g. window management) always take priority over Extension Command shortcuts and can not be overwritten.

i was wondering if there was a way to overwrite this behaviour.
can the solution be just using something else beside the chrome extensions api?

There's no way. You'll have to use an external program like AutoHotKey or write one yourself.

There is no way to change how the keyboard shortcut function on Chrome because they are built-in the web browser. But if you really want to, you can use JavaScript to detect keyboard events and transmit them from the extension to the page.
example of code

correct me if i'm wrong but i don't think we have access to the DOM in the background.js script, so any document or window manipulation isn't possible
